# Laravel - Hide a specific column

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to hide the columns `password` & `OTP` ,that is included in `$user`s result. Actually these 2 columns are part of the users table. My ultimate need is that i need to join 3 tables : `users`,`location`,`user_technical_details` and want to hide the `password` & `OTP` columns in the users table. Can use any methods.  Through any methods, i want to attain this result I've tried many methods. Nothing works. How to solve this? Any suggestions..

**Things i tried:**

**1)**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
$d=$users->makeHidden(['password','OTP']);    
return response()->json([
            'message' => 'profile viewed successfully',
            'data' => $d,
            'statusCode' => 200,
            'status' => 'success'],200);
```

This generates the error - `Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::makeHidden does not exist`

**2)**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
            
$exclude_columns=['password','OTP'];
        $get_columns = array_diff($users, $exclude_columns)->get();
return response()->json([
                'message' => 'profile viewed successfully',
                'data' => $get_columns,
                'statusCode' => 200,
                'status' => 'success'],200);
```

**3)**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
 $d=collect($users->toArray())->except(['password','OTP']);    
   return response()->json([
                'message' => 'profile viewed successfully',
                'data' => $d,
                'statusCode' => 200,
                'status' => 'success'],200);
```

**4)**

protected $hidden = ['password','OTP'];

**5)**

```
$users = DB::table('users')->exclude(['password','OTP','ph_OTP','email_OTP','user_access_token','remember_token'])
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'profile viewed successfully',
                'data' => $users,
                'statusCode' => 200,
                'status' => 'success'],200);
```

This generates the Error -`Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::exclude()`

Comment: @shaedrich i will check

Comment: `protected $hidden...` should work when using Eloquent

Answer (score 3):

when you want to limit the attributes, such as passwords, that are included in your model's array or JSON representation. To do so, add a [$hidden](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) property to your model. In attributes that are listed in the $hidden property's array will not be included in the serialized representation of your model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password','OTP'];
}
```

now in your code you have to use User model instead of DB facade:

```
$users = User::query()
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
```

now, `$users` will not have the hidden attributes